# IIS server running MVC - System.Threading.LockRecursionException

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a basic MVC website, all updates installed.  It is running under Microsoft-IIS/8.5 with Windows server 2012 on AWS.  Error listed below.

The problem seems to be located in a couple heavily used API on the site.  The caller send a JSON object to the function and returns a JSON object.  This works in testing and normally on the site but when I look into my ELMAH logs, I see a lot of the below errors.  My code does not call any locks as shown below so it is my opinion it is happen before the code gets to my function.

I noticed in the error it mentions the routing collection, I don't do any custom routing or change it after the site starts.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Server variables:

```
string="HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH:264;HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:application/json;HTTP_ACCEPT:application/json;HTTP_HOST:my.site.com;HTTP_USER_AGENT:libcurl-agent/1.0"
```

Error message:

```
application="program"
host="WIN-thing"
type="System.Threading.LockRecursionException"
message="Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode."
source="System.Core"
detail="System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.
    at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLockCore(TimeoutTracker timeout)
    at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(TimeoutTracker timeout)
    at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetReadLock()
    at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context)
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)"
```

SUDO code for controller:  The register function is really very simple, you calls a stored procedure that returns a few fields of data and then returns a JSON packet with the values need (two fields).  The received JSON is again, a couple fields.

example register packet: {"Address":"value","company":"name"}

example result packet: {"success":true,"value":"updated 1"}

```
namespace ApMonitor.Controllers
{
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    // passed via json data
    public async Task<JsonResult> Register(Models.ApRegisterModel apReg)
    {
       try 
       {
       using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
           {
             // get device data from SQL (one call)
             var result = await DataLink.RegisterDevice(db, apReg);
             // return json success fail
             if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.DevicePw))
             {
               return DataLink.Fail("Unknown", string.Empty);
             } else {
               return DataLink.Success(result.DeviceData);
             }
           }
       } catch (Exception ex)
       {
         DataLink.ProcessError(ex, "API Controller - Register");
       }
}

public async Task<JsonResult> Log()
{
       try 
       {
           var input = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
           apEvent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.ApEventModel>(input);
       using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
           {
     deviceId = await DataLink.GetDeviceId(db, apEvent.Address);
             foreach(var e in apEvent.Device)
                  db.Events.Add(new Event() { /* ... */ });
             // save data to DB
             var cnt = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     return DataLink.Success(string.Format("updated {0}", cnt));
           }
       } catch (Exception ex)
       {
         DataLink.ProcessError(ex, "API Controller - Log");
       }
   return DataLink.Fail("Unknown", string.Empty);
}

    // moved from another class called DataLink

    internal static JsonResult Success(string value)
    {
        var result = new JsonResult()
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new { success = true, value = value }
        };
        return result;
    }

    internal static JsonResult Fail(string reason, string value)
    {
        var result = new JsonResult()
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new { success = false, reason = reason, value = value }
        };
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are these APIs retrieving information from a file? Seems like a process is raising an exception when it tries to lock a resource for reading. Since IIS is multithreading, it might be concurrency issue but I don't know.

Comment: Based on my interpretation of the stack, the locking issue can be traced back to GetRouteData - what is the body of the API method doing? Are you retrieving route data within an async method, or Parallel.foreach? Perhaps, following on from this - you are doing something similar to this: 
var routeValues = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
if (routeValues != null) 
{
if (routeValues.ContainsKey("action"))
{
    actionName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
}
}
If so, because multiple simultaneous API requests can occur, this may be a race condition on the lock?

Comment: Could you provide the method and class where the exception is being thrown from. I suspect that one of your controllers has some long running code, which is not being handled properly.

Comment: Can you share the code in the API?

Comment: @derloopkat - data is being read from a database.

Comment: @agrath - The body of the API does not touch routing or threading or anything parallel but there is a await.

Comment: @DevEstacion - I have add SUDO code, the register function is pretty much exactly what the real code does, I only changed a name or two.  The log function does a little more checking of the data but those are all string and null compares, nothing complicated.  It all really boils down to read a DB and then write back to said DB.  In fact the register function does not even write back, it is a read only operation.  If I call the function using curl the function returns in less then a second to no more than a few second most of the time, unless I get the above error.